# Flutter Error: Error: Could not resolve the package 'firebase_messaging' in 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, build.gradle

I am building a Flutter Android App that uses Firebase Messaging. However, I get this error when compiling:

```
Error: Could not resolve the package 'firebase_messaging' in 
'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart'.
```

This are the relevant code excerpts:

**Android\Build.Gradle:**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
    
    }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

}

**App\Build.Gradle:**

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
```

}

**pubspec.yaml:**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.2
  firebase_core: ^0.2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0` to your `pubspec.yaml`